# Direct and indirect speech containing let

Tags: grammar

What is the best indirect speech of **I said to the chairman, 'Let's drop the matter' ?**

Is it fine if I use this one **"I proposed to the chairman that we should drop the matter"**?

Comment: "Best" is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Tell me how you would like to do this.

Answer (score 1):

One way, of many.

> I suggested to the chairman that we drop the matter.

The fundamental idea in reported speech is that you are reporting the meaning of what was said, and not the exact wording.  "Let's" is a way of making a suggestion, so you can put that word in the sentence.

Another way to make suggestions is to use "should"

> I said to the chairman that we should drop the matter.

Again, this obeys the fundamental principle of describing the meaning of what was said.

Comment: What if I use this one "I proposed to the chairman that we should drop the matter"?

Comment: I suppose so.  It's a bit over the top for my liking. But if you want formality, you can go all-in and use a subjunctive clause: I proposed that the matter be dropped.